# HTML 5 app image caching issues

Tags: html, caching, html5-appcache, cache-manifest

I am having an issue where css and images although listed in the app cache manifest don’t load from cache when offline. However, the page itself and JS files do function while the application is offline.

Here is a sample of the output:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# App Markup Date: 2/25/2014 5:50:03 PM
# Server Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
NETWORK:

*


CACHE:


http://www.mydomain.com/ec_application_working_files/app.html
http://www.mydomain.com/ec_application_working_files/CCU/chiro.css
http://www.mydomain.com/ec_application_working_files/CCU/cycle.js
http://www.mydomain.com/ec_application_working_files/CCU/forms-ccu.css
http://www.mydomain.com/ec_application_working_files/CCU/jquery-1.6.2.min.js
http://www.mydomain.com/ec_application_working_files/CCU/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css
http://www.mydomain.com/ec_application_working_files/CCU/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js
http://www.mydomain.com/ec_application_working_files/CCU/jquery.form.js
http://www.mydomain.com/ec_application_working_files/CCU/jquery.hoverIntent.js
http://www.mydomain.com/ec_application_working_files/CCU/jquery.modalForm.js
http://www.mydomain.com/ec_application_working_files/CCU/jquery.shuffle.js
http://www.mydomain.com/ec_application_working_files/CCU/jquery.validate.js
http://www.mydomain.com/ec_application_working_files/CCU/loader.gif
http://www.mydomain.com/ec_application_working_files/Images/logo1.png
http://www.mydomain.com/ec_application_working_files/js/app.js
http://www.mydomain.com/ec_application_working_files/js/jquery.js
http://www.mydomain.com/ec_application_working_files/Style/Style.css
http://www.mydomain.com/ec_application_working_files/Style/ui.css
```

For example this resource will not load when offline
http://www.mydomain.com/ec_application_working_files/CCU/loader.gif

The page itself is hosted in
http://www.mydomain.com/Form/app/CCU

The page references the manifest as such:

```
<html lang="en-US"  manifest="/ec_application_working_files/form/app/CCU/manifest.appcache">
```

When I run the application the images and css files don't load. However, If I browse the file URl directly they do load.

Hopefully someone can spot what I am missing here and thank you.